# I cannot connect to iTunes and the App Store from my iPad in iOS6

Tags: itunes

I just updated to iOS6 yesterday. After the update, I cannot connect to the App Store and iTunes on my iPad.

There are no options to click when I'm prompted by this message *"Cannot connect to iTunes/App Store"*.

What should I do?

Comment: Reboot your device to start.

Comment: Are Apple properties the only thing you cannot access? [apple.com](http://apple.com)? Any other websites? Do apps that rely on network activity (Netflix?) function?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at this:

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1398

And if that doesn't work, try this (under Troubleshooting on an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch):

http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1368